# Sending a relational request through api in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, api, jwt, postman

How do I send a request like this through an api?
I get this error even though I passed the user's jwt in the headers

```
ErrorException: Trying to get property 'id' of non-object in file C:\xampp\htdocs\doc\app\Http\Controllers\HistoryApiController.php on line 42
```

This is the store function

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $history = new History;
    $history->history = $request->input('history');
    $history->admin_id = auth()->user()->id;

    $history->save();

    return response()->json([
        'message' => 'History added',

    ]);
}
```

Comment: it means `auth()->user()` is nullable.

Answer (score 0):

this means the token is not valid , check this middleware ('middleware' => 'api') apply on this  routes  to check the token validation if you use tymon package